# HLS Stream, audio/video not synchronized

Tags: android, synchronization, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm working on an application which should stream a video via HLS.
I'm working with a Motorola XT311, Android version: 2.3.4.
I use the Vitamio libary.

The problem is that the video starts about 15-30 seconds after the audio.

My internet connection is solid, so I think that the problem might be due to  hardware or in decoding, I don't know.
Is there any way to play it synchronized?

here is my code:

```
             ...
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.setVideoQuality(MediaPlayer.VIDEOQUALITY_LOW);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.start();
            ....
```

Comment: What does the playlist look like? Does it play synchronized on any other HLS client?

Comment: I didn't try another clients because i couldn't make it run on my device(vlc not supported for my device, bs player alerted missing codec file or something like that although I also downloaded it, I couldn't find working app..) You can contact me at palejandropale@yahoo.com and I'll send you playlist file.

Comment: if you are a passenger and have a synchronization question or answer,but on android native HLS player rather than vitamio, you might want to check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317865/android-hls-audio-starting-before-video-onseek